# I can't find the guy in Whiterun to buy a house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't find the guy to let me buy a house. I have tried everything. I have tried killing my character and restarting the game. What should I do?

Comment: Not sure what's with the down votes here - I mean there's not much explanation but how much more is needed other than "I can't find Proventus Avenicci"? @eumock it may be worth noting where you have already looked in addition to trying the answers below - you could have missed somewhere that he visits regularly, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [Proventus Avenicci](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Proventus_Avenicci). He can be found in Dragonsreach near the Jarl's throne (standing or eating at the tables), on the Great Porch or in the Jarl's quarters. Housing options may not be available while in the latter two places.

If you've taken over Whiterun for the Stormcloaks in the civil war, [Brill](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Brill) is the person to look for instead, provided he's alive. He should also be found inside Dragonsreach.

Comment: What if I proventus is not in any of those places and I am not a storm clock

Comment: @eumock In this case my answer should help

Answer (score 4):

3ventic is correct that you are looking for Proventus Avenicci in your situation (not a Stormcloak). If you're stuck and haven't yet completed the mini-quest for his Daughter, Adrianne (the Whiterun blacksmith, near the main gate) then this will point you to Avenicci. Head to her smithy during the day (it's right near the main gate, can't miss it) and find her - she's usually outside working the smithy but could be inside.

Just speak to her and ask her about "Working the forge all day..." and she'll ask you to [deliver a sword](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Greatsword_for_a_Great_Man) to her father *Proventus* - this will give you a map marker straight to him.

If you've done that quest already go to the Bannered Mare tavern (near the market in Whiterun) and ask Hulda behind the bar if there's any work available - she'll give you a bounty letter from the Palace about [killing some bandits](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bounty:_Bandit_Boss). Once you've killed them you'll need to collect the reward from the steward - who in this case is Proventus - and you'll get a map marker to find him.

**Note** that you can also get the bounty letter from the Jarl or the Steward - not that the steward will help in this situation!